# Namespace problems on Symfony3 upgrade

Tags: namespaces, upgrade, symfony

I'm currently trying to upgrade my Symfony2 application to Symfony3. I have a `SecurityController` that overwrites a `FOSUserBundle\SecurityController`:

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class SecurityController extends ContainerAware
{
    // ...
}
```

But I get a `ClassNotFoundException`:

> Attempted to load class "ContainerAware" from namespace "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Are there any changes that I cannot find in the [upgrade notes](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md). Can someone point me to a way to come over this?

Comment: There is no longer a ContainerAware class.  But on a more interesting note, the only FOSUserBundle version that even loads under S3 is the development branch.  You are most likely using the 1.3 branch which not compatible.  Bottom line, upgrading a FOSUserBundle based app to S3 will be a bit challenging to say the least.

Comment: How do you figure I'm using FOSUB 1.3? Because I don't, I'm using dev at 2.0 branch: `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"`. Thanks for the hint about the removal of `ContainerAware`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the changes from this [PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16424), `ContainerAware` has been deprecated in 2.8 and removed in 3.0 in favor of `ContainerAwareTrait`

Comment: Thank you! Do you know a source how to use `ContainerAwareTrait` instead? Simply extending it instead of `ContainerAware` will most likely not be sufficient?

Comment: You can use it like in this example: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/582f4753a343f230fbe18b4e9a0747d48351ddfb/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Tests/Functional/Bundle/TestBundle/Controller/ProfilerController.php